# How to set Google API credentials to access the AutoML API through a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, google-api, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-automl

I created a simple Google AutoML Natural Language model, following Google's Tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/tutorial). 
Now, I would like to use the API of this model in a function written in [this simple jupyter notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JmS16nwLnGnUHQc2z0WCYIJp9YYOZimg).

To set the API credentials, if I was using a PC, I should use:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path/to/file.json"
```

And add on the Environment Variables on my computer a new variable under system variables %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS% .

But, since I'm using a [jupyter notebook,](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JmS16nwLnGnUHQc2z0WCYIJp9YYOZimg) I'm having difficult on setting the authentication of the API (I don't know how to set the environment variables of the JSON key on it).

How could I do it with [this code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JmS16nwLnGnUHQc2z0WCYIJp9YYOZimg) in a Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The os trick you used is a good hack, which based on Google's suggestions at the time of writing ([ref1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/quickstart), [ref2](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-python), [ref3](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started)). However it is possible to add the credentials through the AutoML instance, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-python). Then the 'os' hack can be avoided. So:

When defining the prediction class instance use this one line:

```
prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient.from_service_account_json("/path/to/file.json")
```